# Required Field validator asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have more than one RequiredFieldvalidator in my markup, I want to check that all fields are entered, and if not I want to show an alert saying so.

Answer (score 0):

Try ValidationSummary control

```
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
```

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.nl/2008/10/validationsummary-example-how-to-use.html